# My cocoa powder is not dark. Is it still dutch processed?

Tags: chocolate, cocoa

I bought whole foods "baking cocoa". On the back in the ingredients section it says "processes with alkali." Then, just above the bar code it says "dutch-processed cocoa". Also, it actually smells like chocolate, unlike my Hershey's unsweetened cocoa. However, it is still very light in color compared to all the pictures I have seen online of dutch processed cocoa. Anyways, my question is, if it is not dark in color, is it still considered dutch processed?

Answer (score 3):

Dutch processed cocoa is "washed" with a potassium carbonate solution to neutralize the acidity to a pH of 7.  While it does give cocoa a richer hue, the color can range quite a bit from a light reddish brown to a dark brown.  Color is less an indicator than the label on the product.  The process is used to provide a more mellow flavor.

Comment: PH could be tested at home; seriouseats suggests testing it by observing how baking soda reacts to it.